# Are we permitted to trust the shechita of a shochet who doesn't keep kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Suppose an otherwise observant and all around excellent shochet is discovered to eat non-kosher food on a regular basis. (Just taking a random example, he's keeping the non-treibored hindquarters of land animals rather than selling them to non-Jews). Are we permitted to trust his shechita? Or does this knowledge disqualify him from service?

Comment: What argument can you put forward in favour of trusting his shechita?

Comment: You've seen him in action a number of times- he keeps his chalifa nice and sharp, and gets a clean one-stroke cut almost all the time, sells the animal to non-Jews when he doesn't

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Rambam in [Hilchot Schechitah 4:14-15](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/971830/jewish/Shechitah-Chapter-4.htm) appears relevant to your case

> A Jew who is an apostate because of his transgression of a particular
>   transgression who is an expert slaughterer may slaughter as an initial
>   and preferred option. A Jew of acceptable repute must check the knife
>   and afterwards give it to this apostate to slaughter with, for it can
>   be presumed that he will not trouble himself to check [the knife].
>
> If, by contrast, he was an apostate because of worship of false
>   deities, one who violates the Sabbath in public, or a heretic who
>   denies the Torah and [the prophecy of] Moses our teacher, as we
>   explained in Hilchot Teshuvah, he is considered as a gentile and [an
>   animal] he slaughters is a nevelah.
>
> [Even though] a person is disqualified as a witness because of his
>   violation of a Scriptural prohibition, he may [still] slaughter in
>   private if he was an expert. For he would not leave something which is
>   permitted and partake of something that is forbidden. This is a
>   presumption that applies with regard to all Jews, even those who are
>   wicked.

In the notes R Eliyahu Touger explains

> Although he repeatedly violates that particular transgression, we do
>   not assume that he will not slaughter correctly.
>
> In his Kessef Mishneh, Rav Yosef Caro cites Chullin 4a which states
>   that as long as if given a choice whether to eat kosher meat or
>   non-kosher meat, the person would choose the kosher meat - even if he
>   would partake of the non-kosher meat if kosher meat was not available
>   - it is permitted to partake of an animal he slaughtered. The Kessef Mishneh continues, explaining that as long as one does not transgress
>   with the intent of angering God, one may partake of an animal he
>   slaughtered.

[...]

> Although it also cites the Rambam's view, the Shulchan Aruch ([Yoreh
>   De'ah 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.2.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) mentions the opinion of the Tur and others who rule that if
>   the person is not an apostate with regard to partaking of non-kosher
>   meat, it is not even necessary to check his knife. He may slaughter in
>   private. If, however, he is an apostate with regard to partaking of
>   non-kosher meat, his knife must be checked. Moreover, if he shows no
>   concern for kashrut at all, his slaughter is not acceptable ([Rama
>   Yoreh De'ah 2:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.2.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

This is of course not meant to be applied in practice - and is only one of possibly many sources on the topic. See for instance [SA YD 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.2.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and ff

Comment: As always, if such a case applies in real life you should consult your local Orthodox rabbi for a ruling.

Comment: @mbloch, your answer was fantastic, much obliged. While learning on other matters, I stumbled accross Tractate Chullin this morning, much of which deals with this very issue